# How to compare current_user to user_id in the model - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

could on kindly advise me - would be very grateful. In my users_controller.rb file i have a condition statement within the `edit action`. i would like to call up the method `profile_editing_rights` from the user.rb model file in the users_controller.rb file

users_controller.rb

```
def edit
  if current_user.company == @user.company && current_user.firstname == @user.firstname
    # can edit only their profile
  else
    redirect_to access_restricted_path
  end
end
```

> i would like to to write this line of code `current_user.company ==
>   @user.company && current_user.firstname == @user.firstname` in the
>   user.rb model file but i am unsure how

i tried the below but does not work:

```
def profile_editing_rights
 self.company == user_id.company && self.firstname == user_id.firstname
end
```

> could one kindly advise me how to write the `profile_editing_rights`
>   method (in the user.rb file) correctly so i can call it up in the users_controller.rb file
>   as below:

```
def edit
  if current_user.profile_editing_rights
    # can edit only their profile
  else
    redirect_to access_restricted_path
  end
end
```

much much appreciated

Comment: As Yahor suggests, have it in a before filter. You can handle the redirection inside the filter, which would be the rails way doing it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def profile_editing_rights
 self.company == user_id.company && self.firstname == user_id.firstname
end
```

it seems that user_id is an integer and isn't an object.
You can not use current_user in the model.

you can put current_user value as a parameter to your method but it's better to check rights in controller.(maybe write a before_filter(action))

Also you can use some auth checker gem: for example 'Pundit'